# Codenameone Slider cannot set height

Tags: slider, codenameone

I am finding it difficult to set the right look and feel of a CN1 Slider control. Essentially i want it to look like the one in the CN1 Default Demo of the Theme window, and have it with the Thumb image to allow the user to set the scroll.

[image]

But when i code it up as per online examples, it comes out skinny on the simulator (as below)
[image]

...but doesn't display the line at all on the actual iphone device.
When i start messing with the methods, such as 'getSliderEmptyUnselectedStyle()' then this makes the background show and can see the progress but its tall and i cannot seem to shrink it.

```
Container container = new Container(new FlowLayout());
container.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
container.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffffff);
Slider slider = new Slider();
// slider.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0);
// slider.getAllStyles().setMarginLeft(0);
// slider.getSliderEmptyUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
// slider.getSliderFullUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
// slider.getSliderEmptySelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
// slider.getSliderFullSelectedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
// slider.getSliderEmptyUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0xffffff);
// slider.getSliderFullUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0x42B72A);
// slider.getSliderEmptySelectedStyle().setBgColor(0xffffff);
// slider.getSliderFullSelectedStyle().setBgColor(0x42B72A);
Style sliderStyle = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Label");
sliderStyle.setFgColor(0);
slider.setThumbImage(
    FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_RADIO_BUTTON_CHECKED, sliderStyle, 4).toImage());

slider.setMinValue(0);
slider.setIncrements(25);
slider.setProgress(entity.getCompletion_pct()); 
slider.setEditable(true); 
container.add(slider);
return container;
```

How can i get it pretty much to the CN1 example?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slider in the example used a 9-piece border or a 3-piece border both of which have a fixed minimum height/width. This minimal height is applied to the way the slider is rendered.

Your code can be made thicker with padding but it will create a problem when you add a thumb. Once you add the thumb it will increase the overall size and make the entire height of the thumb have that background. So you need to style this via the designer and for this specific case you would want to use an image border that is carefully measured to align with the thumb image.

Also notice you used `getAllStyles()` which is wrong. `Slider` is a special case and uses the `Slider` and `SliderFull` UIID so effectively the component has two UIID's and two separate sets of `Style` objects.